# help with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaacces:

```
# Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
Options -Indexes

# Follow symbolic links in this directory.
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule \.(css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

and I have a link on my page:

```
<a href="store/">Store</a>
```

Content loads, but css file is not loaded correctly, it's loaded as it was in */store/* directory. I know I could use absolute link, but I don't want to.
So, shortly:

**www.example.com/store** everything works great

**www.example.com/store/** php looks into /store/ folder, which is wrong

How to make it work in both ways? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

only right way is to use absolute link - otherwise cache will not work propertly and your page will be loading slowly.

Other way is to catch any request for file "somefile.css" and rewrite it to your css - but it will cause problem with cache

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(somefile.css)$ cssfloder/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: wow thanks, i thought you should rather use relative links always :) from now i will always use absolute links

Comment: no , relative links are good when you are NOT using mod_rewrite